# Filling the intersection area of two circles and ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found a picture like this.

[image]

I want to fill the intersection area of two circles and ellipse.
This is what I have done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\coordinate (P) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (Q) at (5,0) ;
\coordinate (R) at (5,4) ;
\coordinate (S) at (0,4) ;
\draw[] (P)--(Q)--(R)--(S)--cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (2,2) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[fill=white] (2.75,2) circle (0.75cm);
\draw[fill=gray] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(3.1,2) (3.24,1.75) (3.46,1.67) (3.5,2) (3.46,2.33) (3.24,2.25) };
\draw[] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(3.46,1.67) (3.77,1.73) (3.94,2) (3.77,2.27) (3.46,2.33) (3.5,2) (3.46,1.67)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I feel the result is not so good, for the ellipse. How to improve it?

Comment: Try `even odd rule` with `fill`? But, actually, what's the question? Your current code seems to do just what you want....

Comment: I feel the result is not so good, for the ellipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `even odd rule` with `fill` as suggested by cfr.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[fill=gray] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
\draw[fill=white,even odd rule] (0.75,0) circle (0.75cm) (1.5,0) circle (0.65cm and 0.15cm);
\node[text=white] at ((-0.5,-0.5) {A};
\node at (0.3,0.2) {B};
\node at (2,1.75) {S};
\draw (-2.5,-2) rectangle (2.5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Harish Kumar, and I add: \draw [shift={(2.,2.)}] plot[domain=-0.23:0.23,variable=\t]({1.*1.5*cos(\t r)+0.*1.5*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.5*cos(\t r)+1.*1.5*sin(\t r)});